# Is it possible to use a variable for fields selection?

Tags: javascript, graphql

So I have this template function like so below.

I'd like to pass an email and some items get about that users email.

The `$email` variable works however I can't seem to get it to accept the second variable for the list of items.

```
const getUser = (email, items = ['email']) => ({
  query: `
    query ($email: String!, $items: [String]) {
      allUsers(condition:{ email: $email }) {
        edges {
          node {
            $items
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    email,
    items,
  },
});
```

How can I dynamically pass a list of items for the query to return?

Comment: I think the best (only?) way to do this would be to use an `if` directive for each field. Or a fragment for every variation you need.

Answer (score 1):

As the query itself is a (template)string, you may try like:

```js
const getUser = (email, items = ['email']) => ({
  query: `
    query ($email: String!, $items: [String]) {
      allUsers(condition:{ email: $email }) {
        edges {
          node {
            ${items}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    email,
    items,
  },
});
```

Comment: Yes this does work however ideally I'd like to use the variables as while for now I'm controlling the input's I may in the future need user defined and I'd rather not risk the injection!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to translate variables into fields is using the `@skip` and `@include` directives. [For example](https://graphql-pokemon.now.sh/?query=query%20MyQuery(%24image%3A%20Boolean!)%20%7B%0A%20%20pokemons(first%3A%2010)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20image%20%40include(if%3A%20%24image)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&operationName=MyQuery&variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22image%22%3A%20true%0A%7D):

```
query MyQuery($image: Boolean!) {
  pokemons(first: 10) {
    name
    image @include(if: $image)
  }
}
```

Here the `image` field will only be included if the `image` variable is true, and skipped if the variable is false. The `@skip` directive works the same way but does the reverse. This is not sustainable for a large number of fields, but it's the only built-in way of doing what you're trying to achieve.

If you're able to modify the server code, then you could potentially create a custom directive that would work similarly, but would accept an array of string values and create a selection set from that list. A variable could then be passed to that custom directive. But again, that assumes you can modify the server-side code, which may not be the case.